# Replace NaN latitude-longitude values of one dataframe with closest non-nan of other dataframe

Tags: pandas, nan, latitude-longitude, geopandas

I have two dataframes: df_1 and df_2. df_1 has missing values for latitude longitude, which represent a linestring. The goal is to find data for the missing values. For this, I have df_2 which contains a manually drawn linestring with lat-lon pairs. In order to replace the nan values in df_1 I already performed:

1. For non-nan values, find the closest (in distance) lat-lon pair of df_2, and add it to columns "closest_latitude" & "closest longitude".

Next step would be to replace df_1 nan values with lat-lon from df_2. We know which lat-lon pair to use, because we already found the closest lat-lon pair for non-nan values. Therefore the following lat-lon in df_2 can be used as as a replacement.

The original df_1 is as follows:

```
    data = {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3'],
        'time': ['2023-06-30 14:32:23','2023-06-30 14:33:23','2023-06-30 14:34:00','2023-06-30 14:34:15','2023-06-30 14:34:45','2023-06-30 14:35:00', '2023-06-30 14:35:10', '2023-06-30 14:35:20'],
        'latitude': [59.9139, "NaN", "NaN", 60.628330, 60.662330, 59.741371, 55.615864, 59.076984],
        'longitude': [10.7522, "NaN", "NaN", 6.401802, 6.892802, 10.176844, 13.040593, 9.864355],
        'closest_latitude_in_df_2': [59.9200, "NaN", "NaN", 60.63000, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
        'closest_longitude_in_df_2': [10.8000, "NaN", "NaN", 11.5000, "NaN", "NaN","NaN", "NaN"]
        }
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['time'])
```

df_2 only contains latitude and longitude pairs of a linestring:

```
data = {'latitude': [59.9000, 59.92000, 59.94000, 59.95000, 59.98000, 60.000000, 60.63000, 60.63500],
        'longitude': [10.2000, 10.8000, 10.8200, 10.8400, 10.8800, 10.9000, 11.5000, 11.5500]}
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**In cases where latitude and longitude are NaN in df_1, I want to replace those NaN values based on closest latitude and longitude pairs that can be found in the linestring in df_2.**

In the end, the final dataframe could look like this:

```
data = {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '3', '3', '3'],
        'time': ['2023-06-30 14:32:23','2023-06-30 14:33:23','2023-06-30 14:34:00','2023-06-30 14:34:15','2023-06-30 14:34:45','2023-06-30 14:35:00', '2023-06-30 14:35:10', '2023-06-30 14:35:20'],
        'latitude': [59.9139, 59.94000, 59.98000, 60.628330, 60.662330, 59.741371, 55.615864, 59.076984],
        'longitude': [10.7522, 10.8200, 10.8800, 6.401802, 6.892802, 10.176844, 13.040593, 9.864355],
        'closest_latitude_in_df_2': [59.9200, "NaN", "NaN", 60.63000, "NaN", "NaN", "NaN", "NaN"],
        'closest_longitude_in_df_2': [10.8000, "NaN", "NaN", 11.5000, "NaN", "NaN","NaN", "NaN"]
        }
df_final = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_final['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_1['time'])
```

In other words, I want to replace NaN values in df_1 with "closest lat-lon pairs" in df_2.

How to find "closest" values to nan lat-lon values? Because I have lat-lon pairs of df_2 for the previous non-nan row in df_1 and I know which values follows that in df_2.

Comment: Just to be clear- were the NaNs in the row "2023-06-30 14:33:23" replaced with 59.068154   9.921612 because they were the second values in df_2? Or was it something else?

Comment: Good point! They were not chosen because they were in the same row. That was my mistake. They were replaced because they were the closest (in distance) to the previous lat-lon pair that is found in both df_1 (closest_latitude, closest_longitude) and df_2. Basically df_1 has missing lat-lon data, I drew a linestring and want to replace NaN with df_2 if they match (as indicated by lat-lon pairs in both dataframes).

Comment: I don't know if I follow....in what sense do you mean "closest"? Because all the lat and lon values in that row were NaN...how can something be close to NaN?

Comment: Hi @Mark, I edited the text/values. Let me know if it isnt more clear. All df_1 NaN rows are encapsulated with non-NaN values. These non-NaN values have a matching "closest" df_2 lat-lon pair based on distance. Because we know which df_2 is assigned to non-NaN in df_1, we can go back to df_2 and see which df_2 lat-lon pair is following. This we would use as replacement for the NaN values in df_1. The lat-lon pairs represent linestrings. df_2 might have a higher resolution, so if df_2 has 4 lat-lon pairs between the non-NaN rows of df_1, we could use every second pair.

Comment: now the values appear out of nowhere (59.940000 appears in df_final, but doesn't appear in df_1 or df_2)

Comment: just go through step by step the process for how that particular value is found

Comment: Hi @Mark, 59.400 is the third latitude value. The starting value in df_1 is 59.9139. Its closest neighbour in df_2 is 59.9200. As next step, I then want to go to df_2, locate 59.9200 and use its following value for replacement of NaN in df_1. I am open for alternatives. Df_2 has a higher frequency of values. But in the end it should be used to replace the NaN lat-lon rows. The closest_latitude/longitude values are already joined in from df_1.